# C++, избавление объекта от квалификатора const

Tags: c++

Хорошим тоном в **C/C++** считается использование **const** везде, где можно.

Например:

```
void setName(const char *const _name)
{
    if (_name == nulltr)
    {
        return;
    }
    delete[] name;
    name = _name;
}
```

В данном примере **const** защищает от глупых ошибок, которые потом будет очень сложно найти. Проблема в том, что **C++**, в отличии от **C**, выдает предупреждениe при:

```
char *s;
const char *const cs;
s = (char*) cs;
```

А поскольку все современные библиотеки следуют хорошему тону использования **const** везде, где только можно, мне стало интересно, как лучше избавляться от квалификатора **const** в коде **C++**?

Использовать ли для этой цели **const_cast** или что-то иное?

Comment: Во-первых, зачем от него избавляться? Во-вторых, ```setName(const char *const _name)``` константность указателя здесь лишняя.

Comment: Это всего лишь пример. Константность указателя бывает нужна, чтобы случайно не изменить этот самый указатель, это важно, когда метод/функция сложны с точки зрения логики.

Comment: Обычно избавляться от квалификатора `const` в коде на C++ не нужно, поэтому давайте-ка Вы приведёте нормальный пример, а мы Вам объясним, почему так делать не нужно.

Comment: Приведенный пример не является нормальным? Вам необходимо привести все дерево вызовов и конструирования?

Comment: Ни С, ни С++ не позволяют делать `s = cs`. Откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: Я знаю, что не позволяют, но в коде на C от квалификатора константности избавляются при помощи (type)value. В плюсах это считается дурным тоном, поэтому я и спрашиваю, как это принято делать. const_cast или есть еще что-то?

Comment: Нет, приведённый пример не является нормальным. Если `name` это `char*`,  а вы хотите туда сохранить `const_cast<char*>(_name)`, то банальный вызов: `setName("name")` является UB. Если у Вас там всё схвачено и такого «никогда не произойдёт», то у Вас всё равно в коде набор костылей. О каком «хорошем тоне» может идти речь в таком случае?

Comment: Это всего лишь пример. Я знаю, что попытка изменить строковой литерал приводит к UB. Например, вот небольшой кусочек кода, в котором используется защита при помощи const всего, чего только можно:
https://github.com/MGNeo/c_hash_multiset/blob/master/c_hash_multiset.c

Да, это C, но для C++ защита еще актуальнее, поскольку объекты могут иметь неочевидное поведение. Проще научиться работать с const, чем разгребать призрачные баги в миллионах строк кода, особенно в дальнейшем, когда большая часть структуры кода забудется.

Comment: Во-первых, там функции. Во-вторых, размазать это по нескольким функциям - вот это будет франкенштейн.

Comment: Интересно, как вы предлагаете разбить операцию вставки данных в хэш-таблицу на несколько функций? Хотелось бы посмотреть на это.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *s;
const char *cs;
s = const_cast<char*>(cs);
```

Но тут возникает вопрос, а для чего Вам нужно избавляться от квалификатора const?

Использование const_cast необходимо лишь для совместимости с библиотеками, написанными на Си, где const не было, и лишь в том случае, если мы знаем что метод гарантировано не вносит в переменную изменений.

В Вашем случае, я так понимаю что переменная `name` имеет тип `char*`, и если Вы присвоите ей значение `_name` с помощью `const_cast`, то никто не гарантирует что в другом методе Вы не захотите изменить `name`, чем поменяете и исходный `_name`.

Думаю, что Вам необходимо просто скопировать себе строку и дальше делать с неё что угодно.

```
void setName(const char *const _name)
{
    if (_name == nulltr)
    {
        return;
    }
    delete[] name;

    const int strSize = strlen(_name);

    name = new char(strSize + 1);
    strcpy(name, _name);

    name = _name;
}
```

**Дополнено**
Если объект все таки нужно сохранить как член класса, то можно его тоже объявить как константный:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void setName(const char *const _name)
    {
        if (_name == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        name = _name;
    }

    const char *name = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass v;
    v.setName("My Name");
}
```

Но, в таком случае, надо понимать, что за удалением памяти должен следить кто-то другой.

**Дополнение2**

Если прям хотите уберечь себя от случайного изменения объекта, используйте временную константную переменную:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void setName(char *_name)
    {
        const char * const tempName = _name;

        //тут делаем дофига операций с tempName

        name = _name;
    }

    char *name = nullptr;
};
```

Если будете передавать константный указатель, затем через const_cast присваивать к своей переменной, то при использование этой переменной, можете получить UB. 
На мой взгляд, проблема высосана из пальца. Тут два пути: если объект не планируется менять, то передаем константный указатель, в всех остальных случаях - неконстантный.

Comment: Избавляться для того, чтобы C++ не считал это ошибкой.

Comment: @Максим, дополнил ответ

Comment: Это всего лишь пример. Суть в том, что в функцию передается какой-то массивный и сложный объект, который нельзя/нежелательно копировать. Квалификатор константности гарантирует, что мы застрахуем указатель на объект или его данные от случайного изменения в теле функции. И только в конце тела функции мы должны связать объект, на который передали указатель, с чем-то. Это довольно сложно объяснить на пальцах, не показывая километры кода.

Comment: @Максим, дополнил ответ

Comment: Нет-нет-нет, указатель-поле внутри класса/структуры не является константным, как и данные, на которые этот указатель указывает, но передавать указатель на такие данные в метод необходимо со всеми const, какими только возможно, потому что внутри метода происходит поэтапная очень сложная логика работы с заданным объектом, внутри которой желательна защита от случайного изменения тех или иных данных. В общем, я понял, в C++ в таких случаях используют const_cast, чтобы не было лишних предупреждения компилятора о "старом" способе приведения (type)value.

Comment: @Максим В таком случае этот метод явно стоит разбить на несколько меньших методов.

Comment: Это невозможно, потому что тогда вместо четкого и ясного, пускай и сложного, алгоритма мы получим размазанный по нескольким методам код, который невозможно поддерживать и понимать. Например, размазать по методам добавление объекта в хэш-таблицу - крайне плохая идея.

Comment: @Максим "сложный" это обычно противоположность "четкого и ясного". По вашей же ссылке функция `c_hash_multiset_insert` прямо-таки просит, чтоб ее разделили. По поводу определения оптимальной длины методов и критериев их разбиения написано уже немало.

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете разделять практически атомарное действие на несколько только лишь потому, что кода получается 200 строк? Хорошо, каким образом вы предлагаете разнести вставку данных в хэш таблицу на несколько функций?

Comment: @Максим https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9090816

Answer (score 2):

Гм...

> Хорошим тоном в C/C++ считается использование const везде, где можно.

Хорошим тоном считается использование чего-то там, где это разумно. Любитель молотка может навязывать его для забивания шурупов потому, что "*можно*", но разумный человек возьмет отвертку.

Например,

```
int square(const int x) { return x*x; }
```

Да, тут *можно* писать `const` - но вот *нужно* ли? Чего вы этим добьетесь?

Избавляться от `const` в коде С++ необходимо по сути только при работе с уже имеющимся кодом, в котором не использован `const`, но ведет код себя так, как будто он написан (причем это поведение **гарантируется** и в будущих версиях). И то - бывает, что надежнее сделать не-`const` копию и отдать ее такому старому коду, особенно если такой гарантии будущего константного поведения нет...

Comment: Как всегда - просьба к минусующему пояснить, в чем я неправ.

Comment: При чем тут молоток и шурупы? При чем тут разумно или не разумно? Я ведь интересуюсь совершенно конкретным вопросом, я не прошу совета по поводу того, нужно мне это или нет. Если спрашиваю, значит мне это нужно. А нужно мне это потому, что в метод или функцию передаются указатели на те или иные данные. Сами данные не константные, но передавать в функцию/метод их нужно именно как константные, потому что внутренняя логика функции/метода такова, что очень желательно защитить параметры функции от изменения до того момента, когда необходимо будет эту защиту снять.

Comment: И да, огромная куча кода в проекте написана на C, и его надо состыковать с C++.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы недопонимаете **сути** `const`, отсюда и ваши вопросы. Так сказать, XY-проблема...

Comment: Я понимаю суть const. Видимо вы не понимаете сути вопроса.

Comment: http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/09/const-1.html Посмотрите, возможно станет понятно, с чем связан мой вопрос.